# Linux: Low memory GNOME distro or VM that takes up < 600 MB total disk space on VM?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine, debian, gnome

I'm trying to get the Hamster time tracking Gnome applet working on OS X using seamless mode.

I'm presuming with Gnome I can create a Gnome panel, with just the Hamster time tracker applet in it, taking up minimal screen space on my OS X system.
I have a ton of time tracked already that I will import.

So I'm looking for a VM or distro that supports VirtualBox seamless mode, not all distros do!

I have a preference for a Debian based system because as a frequent Ubuntu user, I am used to apt-get all the time.

Because it will be running constantly, it must consume a small amount of RAM and minimal swap.
(I need all the RAM I can get.)
I have low disk space at times also (Xcode eats so much space, I will have to repartition.)
It's always nice to have a small download also.

The more pre-made the setup, the better - so premade VM's are good as well as ISOs.

Know any distros that fit the bill?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try to run hamster natively, instead of virtually.
According to [projecthamster](http://projecthamster.wordpress.com/about/), "Hamster is written in PyGTK, using SQLite for data storage", and per [pygtk.org](http://pygtk.org/), "PyGTK applications are truly multiplatform and they're able to run, unmodified, on Linux, Windows, MacOS X and other platforms."  [razorsql.com](http://www.razorsql.com/articles/sqlite_mac.html) says sqlite3 is included in Mac OS X.

Regarding how to start hamster without a button, a [guy with a long name](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/workarounds-for-using-hamster-time-tracker-in-ubuntu-unity-or-gnome-shell/) writes,

> Since hamster applet is nothing but a Python app, you can technically invoke it as a standalone application instead of an applet. Most of the time, the utility must be in your path. You can invoke it as ..."

Comment: Thanks, I'd love to but I need the feature that shows the present task as part of a system dock, and also there are several Linux things that my system could use, like Geany and a bunch of awesome scripts that just work on Linux, but would take significant reconfiguration on Mac OS X.

Comment: Project Hamster presently has Gnome and DBUS dependencies.